# Specify only column position in css grid 2-column layout

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

My purpose is to set 'product' always in left column (column 1), my 'box' always shows in right column (column 2). But my first few cells in right column are always skipped. How should I make no cell is skipped in right column?

I don't want to set col and row position of each cell, I just want to set column, then the box will flow from 1 row to nth row.

[image]

You can see my [code pen here](https://codepen.io/nicolasxu-bg/pen/MGVPEm).

```css
.two-col-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 45%;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
.two-col-grid-container .product {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.two-col-grid-container .box {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-col-grid-container">
  <div class="product">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product">Product 5</div>
  <div class="product">Product 6</div>
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `grid-auto-flow: dense` to your container:

```
.two-col-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 45% 45%;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense; /* new */
}
```

```css
.two-col-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 45%;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* new */
}

.two-col-grid-container .product {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two-col-grid-container .box {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-col-grid-container">
  <div class="product">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product">Product 5</div>
  <div class="product">Product 6</div>
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

The [**`grid-auto-flow`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property) property controls how the *auto placement algorithm* flows items into the grid.

The default value is `row`, which means that automatically placed items are flowed into the grid row-by-row, based on source order. That's what you're seeing in your layout.

The `dense` value doesn't necessarily follow a linear flow: it attempts to fill in empty cells that may appear earlier in the grid.